# I am getting an infinite loop when I run my program. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, loops, infinite-loop

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuDRk.png)
This is a finance problem I was working on. I have a loop set up but after it displays all of the correct values, it displays all "0" for every variable infinitely. My Python versions is 3.6.7 running on Ubuntu.

I have tried to set it up so the current_balance is greater than the ending_balance but the problem is still there.

```py
price = float(input("Enter initial price: "))
INTEREST_RATE = 0.12 / 12
DOWN_PAYMENT = price * .9
monthly_payment = 0
ending_balance = 0
interest = 0
principal = 0
month = 0

print("%s%18s%10s%11s%9s%13s" % ("Month", "Current Balance", "Interest", "Principal", "Payment", "End Balance"))

month = 1
current_balance = DOWN_PAYMENT
interest = current_balance * INTEREST_RATE
monthly_payment = current_balance * 0.05
principal = monthly_payment - interest
ending_balance = current_balance - principal

while ending_balance > 0:
    print("%d%18.2f%10.2f%11.2f%9.2f%13.2f" % (month, current_balance, interest, principal, monthly_payment, ending_balance))
    month += 1
    current_balance = ending_balance
    interest = current_balance * INTEREST_RATE
    monthly_payment = current_balance * 0.05
    principal = monthly_payment - interest
    ending_balance = current_balance - principal
```

There are no errors, just an infinite loop. The program should be over once ending_balance = 0.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code. How are you assigning all those variables?

Comment: Well, since you "print" a line containing all of the apparently-relevant variables, why don't you add a comment listing a few of those lines?  The most obvious culprit would of course be that `principal` has become negative ...

Comment: After adding Stephen's changes, the program is slow at the end. I think it's because the principal is already a fraction of your tiny current balance. So I think changing the condition to `while principal > 0.01` or other value would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point is your problem.  To end the loop use:

```
while ending_balance >= 0.005:
```

The current balance is always getting smaller, but you only show two decimal digits.

Comment: I took your advice and did just that, and it worked. But it seems like it is going on for too long. There were over 200 months. I have put up the rest of my code if you could take a look at that and let me know what the problem may be.